# How to use "$@" in a Git alias?

Tags: git

`git log --name-status --pretty=format: | sed '/^$/d' | cut --fields=2- | sort | uniq --count | sort --numeric-sort --reverse | head` prints the 10 most edited files in a Git repo (based on [this](https://github.com/jez/git-heatmap/blob/443aae332eeb5455f857b41602153bf48e46579f/git-heatmap)). I want to create a Git alias `most-edited` for this command with one caveat: **the command should put any extra arguments into the `git log` command.** This would allow me to run `git most-edited 'foo bar/' baz/` to get the most edited files in the `foo bar` (note the space) and `baz` directories.

In a script this would be as simple as adding `-- "$@"` to the `git log` command. However, if I create an alias `most-edited = !git log --name-status --pretty=format: -- "$@" | sed '/^$/d' | cut --fields=2- | sort | uniq --count | sort --numeric-sort --reverse | head` the arguments are instead passed to the last command in the pipeline, `head`. Is there some way to pass the arguments to `git log`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the alias, define a function followed by an immediate call to the function. When the alias is expanded, any additional arguments on the command line become arguments to that function.

```
most-edited = '!f () { git log --name-status --pretty=format: -- "$@" | sed '/^$/d' | cut --fields=2- | sort | uniq --count | sort --numeric-sort --reverse | head; }; f'
```

Comment: Nice! I had to fix the quoting though, and ended up with `most-edited = "!f() { git log --name-status --pretty=format: -- \"$@\" | sed '/^$/d' | cut --fields=2- | sort | uniq --count | sort --numeric-sort --reverse | head; }; f"`

Answer (score 2):

Save your shell script to a file named `git-most-edited` somewhere in the `$PATH`, like `~/.local/bin/`, and do `chmod 755` on the file.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

git log --name-status --pretty=format: -- "$@" | sed '/^$/d' | cut --fields=2- | sort | uniq --count | sort --numeric-sort --reverse | head
```

You can then run `git most-edited` and Git will invoke your shell script for you.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: you can also use `"!git log --name-status --pretty=format: \"$@\" | sed '/^$/d' | cut --fields=2- | sort | uniq --count | sort --numeric-sort --reverse | head #"`.  The final `#` is required.

#### Long

Both [iBug's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69331141/1256452) ("write your own script and make it Git-callable") and [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69331124/1256452) ("use an alias that invokes a shell function") work fine, and are fully generic.  There's one more possibility here, which is quite tricky, but also illustrative.  I like to use the `wc` command to help show how the arguments get broken up:

```
[alias]
    visargs = "!wc head \"$@\" tail #"
```

Running:

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git visargs "one two" three
```

produces this output:

```
18:58:34.031386 git.c:702               trace: exec: git-visargs 'one two' three
18:58:34.031749 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git-visargs 'one two' three
18:58:34.032434 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: 'wc head "$@" tail #' 'one two' three
wc: head: open: No such file or directory
wc: one two: open: No such file or directory
wc: three: open: No such file or directory
wc: tail: open: No such file or directory
       0       0       0 total
```

Note how the arguments were passed through to `wc` correctly: `one two`, as a single argument, got through as a single argument, and `three` got through as a single argument as well.  The `wc` command got the arguments `head` and `tail` separately, and did *not* get a repeated set of arguments, even though, as we can see from the `trace` lines, the command run was really:

```
trace: run_command: 'wc head "$@" tail #' 'one two' three
```

The first expression is fed straight to `sh` as its `-c` argument.  The remaining expressions are `$1`, `$2`, and so on.  That's why the `$@` works where it is, but also why we need the comment character: without the `#`, the arguments get tacked onto the final part of the alias expansion.

Comment: Nice! I don't understand why the `#` makes a difference, though. I was able to simplify it a little bit more into `most-edited = !git log --name-status --pretty=format: \"$@\" | sed '/^$/d' | cut --fields=2- | sort | uniq --count | sort --numeric-sort --reverse | head "#"`

Comment: Without the final `#` you wind up passing the `$@` arguments to `head` too. I end up preferring the "define function f, then invoke f" sequence, which is much more understandable. This particular variant is just useful to observe how Git invokes the shell.

Comment: "Without the final # you wind up passing the $@ arguments to head too." I just don't understand *why* that is. It doesn't work that way in Bash scripts, for one thing.

Comment: I know - but try it out; it happens.